# How to implement drawLayer:InContext in the implementation file of a UIView?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have a UIView in which I draw things in the drawRect method. I would like to overlay a CALayer over the UIView CALayer (self.layer) that would draw a subset of the things I draw in the drawRect. Basically, I draw a lot of circles in drawRect, and I would like to highlight some them on the overlay. I get the coordinates of the circles from a model object that is a property of the UIView.

My first attempt was to add a sublayer `s` to the UIView layer, set its delegate to the UIView and call its `setNeedsDisplay` method when needed, but  `drawLayer:InContext` is called by both layers (`s` and self.layer). This doesn't work:

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    if (layer == s ) {
    // draw stuffs for s
    }
    else if (layer==self.layer) {
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

results in a black UIView. I would like to draw `s` from a place where I have access to my data model, and other variables useful for the drawing (width of lines..). I have kinda solved the problem by moving the drawing of `s` to a separate object, but this forces me to  also set a pointer of the model in this object, and also copy other parameters.

So my question is: in a UIView drawing its content using drawRect, how to add a sublayer which delegate is the same UIView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass UIView and in that subclass override `+ (Class)layerClass` with your own CALayer subclass. Then that UIView will use that subclass when it creates its backing layer. Your CALayer subclass would then have an override for `drawLayer`.

You can put this CALayer subclass (interface and implementation) in your UIView subclass.